# Is nullptr the same as zero?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and have gotten to pointers. I am struggling to understand the difference between initializing a pointer to zero and initializing it to nullptr, as demonstrated below.

```cpp
int *p = 0;
int *p1 = nullptr;
```

My understanding is that p and p1 are both null pointers. Does this mean that nullptr is equivalent to zero, and that both p and p1 are pointing to the same address (that is, the address for zero)?

If they are the same, why would I want to use nullptr when I could just use zero? If they aren't the same, why is it useful to have multiple ways to declare a null pointer instead of one way?

Comment: In this case there is no difference between the pointers, both are null.

Comment: template<class F, class A>
void Fwd(F f, A a){f(a);}
void func(int* i){} #####  func(NULL)// Fine #####  func(0);// Fine// #####  Fwd(func, nullptr);// Fine  #####  Fwd(func, NULL);  **// ERROR: No function func(int)**